# Contextual key bindings when a specific context menu is open

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, plugin-fzf

I recently installed [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) CLI fuzzy search utility, and the accompanying [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) file with it.  They both work great, and I have been enjoying my experience with them thus far.

However, I'd like to keep the default key bindings of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to move up and down through things like the buffer list when invoking fzf within vim.

Unfortunately I tend to use Neovim / Vim within tmux sessions quite frequently, and I have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to move about the various panes within a tmux window, thus not allowing me to move about the buffers list presented by fzf.

Does Vim / Neovim support a "contextual key binding"?  *Not sure if that is what it should be called or not*", but basically I'd like to have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> work within fzf when a buffer list "window / modal" is present, and then also work to move about tmux panes when the buffer list presented by fzf is not present.

Basically I'd like to have my cake  and eat it  at the same time.

**Update**

fzf can be brought up within the context of the Vim `command mode`, I hope that helps clarify things.

Also, forgot to mention I'm using [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) to seamlessly switch between panes from a Vim session and those of a tmux session.

Below is a picture of what I attempted to describe above using words.

[image: fzf-context-within-vim]

cheers 
Chris

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but this seems like a tmux/fzf interaction, not anything to do with vim.  How would tmux know what you mean when you type ctrl+j?

Comment: @Mass see my amendment please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following lines in my `~.tmux.conf`, and they allow me to continue to use <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> for navigation within Vim (between windows and also between CtrlP results), and yet also use them for navigating between tmux panes:

```
# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits and of emacs (but not emacs splits)
bind-key -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iqE '(vim|emacs)' && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind-key -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iqE '(vim|emacs)' && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind-key -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iqE '(vim|emacs)' && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind-key -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iqE '(vim|emacs)' && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
```

A quick google suggests that [I stole the idea from here](https://gist.github.com/mislav/5189704), although I bear sole responsibility for the addition of the half-completed support for emacs.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I'll give this a test drive  here in a sec.

Comment: worked as described , thanks again for sharing, and sorry you have to use emacs.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯